# How to create component instance programmatically in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

I have a wizard with steps. Each step is a Vue component that knows how to operate their piece of data. Each step has a `restore` function that has the logic to restore the object in that particular step.

There are some specific steps that require navigation away from the app (like connecting a Google calendar with OAuth flow).

During return to the application I need to restore the object up until the current step. And since each step owns their piece of data I was using Vue.extend to create previous steps and I was calling the `restore` method of each step.

Something like this:

Step1 -> Step2 -> Step3 -> Navigation away from the app -> Return back to the app -> Restore data from Step1 - Step3 -> Proceed to Step 4

In Vue 2 it was like this:

```
import WizardStep from "./WizardStep.vue"

let WizardStepClass = Vue.extend(WizardStep)
let wizardStep = new WizardStepClass()

let myObject = {}
await wizardStep.restoreData(myObject)
```

WizardStep.vue:

```
...
export default {
...
    methods: {
        async restoreData(dataObj){
        //specific logic to fill in dataObj
        }
    }
}
```

`Vue.extend` was quick and easy approach to accomplish that but now I'm stuck. How to do that in Vue 3?

Comment: Consider explaining your case further. It's not evident that `new WizardStepClass` was an acceptable solution previously. If WizardStepClass is just reusable logic without presentation then a component isn't the proper place for it

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask. yes, you are correct that `new WizardStepClass` was questionable in the first place. Had to reconsider my approach and to store all the data in the browser session storage instead. This way I can restore it without touching the previous steps which surely smelled. Separately, WizardStep is a fully functional component with presentation and logic, it was just oversimplified example. Thanks again. If you'd to post your comment as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Generally that's a good case for a store with persist plugin, especially considering that data still needs to be reactive, so you don't have to sync with LS manually